# SQL & Python - Getting a dictionary of size 1 with multiple columns

Tags: python, cx-oracle

Using cx_Oracle, I am trying to get two columns from the database, both are in the same single row.

When I do something similar to

```
select apple, orange from fruit where id='3'
```

I expected to get back {0: 'apple3', 1: 'orange3'}, but instead I am getting {0: ''apple3', 'orange3''}

What is the best solution to get the result I expected?

Here is my code:

```
curs.execute(code)

result = curs.fetchall();

# I want to use a dictionary
vals = {}
for row in result:
    vals[len(vals)] = str(row)
```

Comment: If it's only one row for sure, try changing curs.fetchall() for curs.fetchone()

Comment: Have you tried to print ``row``? You're converting whatever ``row`` is to a ``str``, so information might get lost.

Comment: How silly of me. Thanks, Mike Scotty. I've been working on this project way too long to be thinking straight.